# Wordpress Rest API to call page data associate with custom meta

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, rest-api

I have an ajax rest api called to retrieve certain page data, the call was success but it's come with blank meta, is there any workaround to call api associated with meta data along?

```
var request = jQuery.ajax({
    url : '/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/'+post_id,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json"
});

request.done(function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
    
});

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    console.log('fail')
});
return false;
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to wpse! are you using ACF by any chance? if you do, make sure you have the latest version **>= 5.11**, after you updated the plugin you will have a option to show acf fields in restapi.

Comment: Here are the [release notes](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/blog/acf-5-11-release-rest-api/) for ACF 5.11, the biggest improvment was that particular feature, thanks to this question I now know about it =D.

Comment: no, I'm not using ACF